# After Effects bodymovin into PIXI.js

Tags: canvas, pixi.js, svg-animate, after-effects, bodymovin

In this after effect [example](https://codepen.io/airnan/pen/yapJWq), It show the option `renderer: 'pixi'` I would like to know whether this will use the pixi js renderer technique or else it will create a pixi js canvas for making animation.

Also would like to know is it possible to load after effect animations into pixi js?